# Swift: Function with inout-Closure

Tags: swift, closures, inout

I have the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myInt: Int
    var myString: String
}
```

This struct should be edited in a function like this:

```
func editMyStruct(action: (inout MyStruct) -> ()) {
    var mutableMyStruct = MyStruct(myInt: 10, myString: "Foo")
    action(&mutableMyStruct)
    //do something with the modified 'mutableMyStruct' ...
}
```

However, I do have difficulties to call `editMyStruct(action: (inout MyStruct) -> ())`.

```
editMyStruct(action: { myStruct in
    myStruct.myInt = 20
    myStruct.myString = "Bar"
})
```

XCode throws the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Does anyone of you know, how to fix this issue?

Looking forward to your response!

Comment: The behavior of inout closure arguments was changed in I believe Swift 4.0.3. Which version of Swift are you using? Also, are there other overloads of `editMyStruct`? It works fine for me (Swift version 4.0.3, tested in REPL).

Comment: @Palle Argh! Shame on me. I noticed that the mentioned error was thrown due to having another function with the same signature ... Yeah you're right, the above code is working properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Found the answer!</s>

The syntax for the `editMyStruct(action: (inout MyStruct) -> ())` must be:

```
editMyStruct(action: { (myStruct: inout MyStruct) in
    myStruct.myInt = 20
    myStruct.myString = "Bar"
})
```

**EDIT**

Argh! Shame on me. I noticed that the mentioned error was thrown due to having another function with the same signature ... The code from above is fine ;)

Comment: That's not necessary, the code in your question compiles just fine.